# laravel Mysql Greek letters showing like?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Mysql table
logs Collation is latin1_swedish_ci

app.blade

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

This is my Controller

```
        $PDO = DB::connection('mysql')->getPdo();
        //$PDO->exec("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"); // i try this  Not working ...

        $billingStmt = $PDO->prepare("select * from logs");
        $billingStmt->execute();
        $usersBills = $billingStmt->fetchAll((\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
        //header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); // i try this  Not working ...
        $logs = ($usersBills);
```

I try to get query from model but no luck 
in mysql database characters store like this

```
??????????????????????
```

In my old php code (No laravel)  mysqli everything working fine with GREEK charackters

Comment: use `utf-8` encoading

Comment: Characters are stored in database like '???' or are showing on page like this? Can you connect to database with some software (phpmyadmin, mysql workbench etc) and inspect table?

Comment: Yes like  this '???????' https://gyazo.com/b8c6315661283e288cebf8f2e70c2e99 but in my old code php (NO Laravel) its working fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my `MySQL` table field from `Collation` to `utf8_unicode_ci`

[image: utf8_unicode_ci]